# How to create a custom field using a uuid?

Tags: python, uuid, peewee

I use MySQL. For an `id` field of type `char(36)` I tried to do so:

```
import uuid

class Example(BaseModel):
    id = FixedCharField(uuid.uuid4),
    name = TextField(column_name='name')

record.create(name = 'name')
```

After you create a record has `id` = `''`. How to fix this?

Comment: You did not put "default=" -- FixedCharField(default=uuid.uuid4)

Comment: @coleifer Thanks!